# Fourier transform of a Radon measure

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-distributions

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $\mathbb R^d$
with finite total mass: I guess that it is a tempered distribution on $\mathbb R^d$ and thus one may consider its Fourier transform. Now I guess that  its Fourier transform $\hat µ$ is a bounded uniformly continuous function. Are these guesses correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Fourier transform of a finite measure is the uniformly continuous bounded function
$$
\hat{\mu}(x)= \int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{-i x \cdot y} d \mu(y) =: f(x)
$$

Now, if we treat $\mu$ as a tempered distribution, its Fourier transform as a distribution is the regular distribution given by $f$, that is
$$
\langle \mathcal{F}(\mu), g \rangle  =\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(x) g(x) dx \qquad \forall g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)
$$

For distributions with compact support, this is Theorem 12.3 in [these notes](http://www.math.chalmers.se/%7Ehasse/distributioner_eng.pdf). Now if you want to extend this to finite measures, you can use the fact that for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists some $A>0$ such that the total mass of $\mu$ outside $[-A,A]^d$ is less than $\epsilon$.